# Помогите найти похожие книги по тегам

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Есть таблицы: 
book (id, title)
tag (id, tag)
bind_book_tag (id_book, id_tag)

Первая для книг, вторая для тегов, третья для связки тегов и книг (по id, т.е. в одной строке в столбце id_book указывается id книги из таблицы book и в столбце id_tag - id тега из таблицы tag). У каждой книги есть несколько тегов. id каждой книги связано с id нужным тегом отдельной строкой в таблице bind_book_tag.

Как для одной книги вытащить релевантные (похожие) книги по тегам? Можно несколькими запросами. Приложение на php.

Answer (score 3):

Примерно так:

```
select book.id, book.title
from book
join bind_book_tag bbt on
  book.id = bbt.id_book 
  and bbt.id_tag in 
    (select id_tag from bind_book_tag where id_book=$current_book_id)
having count(bbt.id_tag) = (select count(id_tag) from bind_book_tag where id_book=$current_book_id)
```

Можно этот запрос разбить на два. Т.е. сначала получить тэги книги, посчитать их и заменить вложенные запросы на список тэгов и количество тэгов соответственно.

В качестве развития идеи можно проверять не на точное количество совпадающих тэгов. Например, можно ограничить снизу, чтоб хотя бы один тэг совпал: `having count(bbt.id_tag)>0`. И сделать сортировку по `count(bbt.id_tag)` по убыванию...

ЗЫ запрос не проверял, возможны ошибки.